# C Array Initializer With Different Sizes?

Tags: c, arrays, size

I'm trying to make a multidimensional array, which contains lots of data.

However, I don't know the initializer size of the middle array since this is always different for each array level.

It looks like this:

```
 char* spawnableVehicles[3][][3] = {
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
 }
```

How do I initialize the size of the middle array?

Comment: You cannot have an array of arrays that are different sizes. Each element of an array must be the same type, including size. (`spawnableVehicles[0]` cannot be an array of five things while `spawnableVehicles[1]` is an array of three things.) You must either specify a maximum size for the middle dimension that encompasses all cases, or you must use a different data structure.

Comment: You can't have a different size for any inner array. They all must be the same size. So, choose an appropriate maximum and use that: `char* spawnableVehicles[3][8][3]` ... or stop using your array approach and switch to pointers with `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Okay, clear. What would be a appropriate data structure for my case?

Comment: @AppelFlap: Your question does not state much about the situation. An array of pointers to arrays might be suitable, with each pointer being set to an address returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify all the indices clearly. The definition as **spawnableVehicles[3][][3]** yields to error while when I defined **spawnableVehicles[30][30][30]** the error vanished. I also wrote a code to check this out:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char* spawnableVehicles[30][30][30] = {
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
      {
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
           {"test1", "test2", "test3"},
      },
 };
 for (int i=0;i<30;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<30;j++){
        for (int k=0;k<30;k++){
            if (spawnableVehicles[i][j][k]!=NULL){
                // printing spawnableVehicles[i][j][k] when it has a value other than NULL
                cout<<i<<"   "<<j<<"   "<<k<<"   "<<spawnableVehicles[i][j][k]<<"\n";
            }
        }
    }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

with the following result:

```
0   0   0   test1
0   0   1   test2
0   0   2   test3
0   1   0   test1
0   1   1   test2
0   1   2   test3
0   2   0   test1
0   2   1   test2
0   2   2   test3
0   3   0   test1
0   3   1   test2
0   3   2   test3
0   4   0   test1
0   4   1   test2
0   4   2   test3
1   0   0   test1
1   0   1   test2
1   0   2   test3
1   1   0   test1
1   1   1   test2
1   1   2   test3
1   2   0   test1
1   2   1   test2
1   2   2   test3
2   0   0   test1
2   0   1   test2
2   0   2   test3
2   1   0   test1
2   1   1   test2
2   1   2   test3
2   2   0   test1
2   2   1   test2
2   2   2   test3
2   3   0   test1
2   3   1   test2
2   3   2   test3
2   4   0   test1
2   4   1   test2
2   4   2   test3
2   5   0   test1
2   5   1   test2
2   5   2   test3
2   6   0   test1
2   6   1   test2
2   6   2   test3
2   7   0   test1
2   7   1   test2
2   7   2   test3

--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.08576 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Seems to be suitable for my situation. Just a question, how come on the second line it jumps from 4 to 0 again?

Comment: Well, in which case you mean? I don't see any 4 to 0 in the second line. Or I misunderstood you...

Comment: This is because of the priority of increments in values of i,j,k. Note that first of all, k increases. When no more increment is possible (say, spawnableVehicles[i][j][k] is NULL) the increment happens next in j similarly after that in i. That's why we have a transition from [0 4 2] to [1 0 0] because for all the vectors [i][j][k] with i=0, j>=4 and k>3 we have spawnableVehicles[i][j][k]=0 and the next immediate non-NULL spawnableVehicles[i][j][k] is spawnableVehicles[1][0][0]

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Thanks!